# Unable to view text in columnHeaders in jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I am trying to create a jasper report (pdf format) that displays list of calls handled. The report is getting created but the heading are not being shown. I have tried to make changes in style but nothing seems to work for this case.

I am using the following libs for this

```
-    jasper-compiler-jdt-5.5.15.jar
-    jasperreports-6.2.0.jar
-    jasperreports-fonts-6.0.0.jar
-    itext-2.1.7.jar
-    itextpdf-5.5.10.jar
```

Following is part of jrxml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="StockReport" pageWidth="1200" pageHeight="600" columnWidth="50" leftMargin="35" rightMargin="35" topMargin="50" bottomMargin="40">

<parameter name="Title" class="java.lang.String"/>


<field name="id" class="java.lang.Long"/>
<field name="dateTime" class="java.util.Date"/>

 --------------------------------------------------

<title>
<band height="50" splitType="Stretch">
    <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
        <reportElement x="0" y="5" width="960" height="30"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center">

            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{Title}]]>    
            </textFieldExpression>
   </textField>
</band>
</title>
<pageHeader>
<band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
    <textField>
        <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="55" y="5" width="1000" height="15" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#8c8c8c"/>
        <textElement textAlignment="Center">
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Daily Reports"]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>
</band>
</pageHeader>
<columnHeader>
   <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
    <staticText>
        <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="55" y="4" width="30" height="15" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#b30000"/>
        <textElement textAlignment="Left">
            <font isBold = "true"/>
        </textElement>
        <text>
            <![CDATA["Record Id"]]>
        </text>
    </staticText>
    <staticText>
         <reportElement positionType="Float" mode="Opaque" x="85" y="4" width="100" height="15" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#b30000"/>
        <textElement>
            <font isBold = "true"/>
        </textElement>
        <text>
            <![CDATA["Date/Time"]]>
         </text>
    </staticText>

 -------------------------------------------


 </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
   <band height="80" splitType="Stretch">
    <textField>
        <reportElement x="65" y="4" width="15" height="60"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="Left"/>
        <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Long"><![CDATA[$F{id}]]>
        </textFieldExpression>
    </textField>
    <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
        <reportElement positionType="Float" x="95" y="4" width="90" height="60"/>
    <textElement/>
    <textFieldExpression class="java.util.Date"><![CDATA[$F{dateTime}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>

 -----------------------------------------------------
```

This is my jrxml file.

It is displaying all the data correctly except the column headers. I cannot understand what the problem is. Also I am getting the following warning

```
WARN  [net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.PdfGlyphRenderer] -------- Unpatched iText found, cannot use glyph rendering
```

Screenshot of generated pdf (some details have been scratched off)

[image]

Any help will be highly appreciated.

I am not using iReport tool. Currently the use of the same is restricted to our group. Please suggest a solution other than this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is unclear. `The report is getting created but the heading are not being shown.` - What does it mean? Is it blank, or `???` is showing? Or region was skipped? How did you check results (pdf, xls)? Are you using font extentions?

Comment: @Alex I cannot understand what the problem is. Currently it is appearing blank. I assumed that it was because of the font style use. But I am not sure. I am new to jasper reports. I dont really understand all the terms used. Please understand. I am trying to generate the report in pdf format

Comment: 1) Try to remove `reportFont` row (3rd at your sample); 2) Try to use font from *jasperreports-fonts-6.0.0.jar*; 3) Try to use styles and use style at *column header*.

Comment: One of your issues is also that you are mixing iText versions.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse Could you please elaborate? I am new to jasper reports that is why.

Comment: @AlexK I tried as you suggested. But it still doesnt solve the issue also I am getting the same warning `WARN  [net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.PdfGlyphRenderer] -------- Unpatched iText found, cannot use glyph rendering`

Comment: You should post the small sample of your best try (*jrxml* file) and screenshot of output *pdf*

Comment: @AlexK Does this have anything to do with band height or row height or font color used? I have tried with other font colors but height I cannot because it creates overflow error.

Comment: You are mixing 2.1.7 and 5.5.10.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse isnt itext used by itextpdf? and 2.1.7 happens to be the latest version available. besides every other text except column headers are being rendered clearly. I dont think the problem is associated with itext.

Comment: No, "itext" and "itextpdf" are exactly the same product. The latest version available is 7.0.3, but that is a total rewrite and not backwards compatible. The latest version still compatible with your code, is 5.5.11, released March this year. 2.1.7 (released July 2009) is a deprecated version and is no longer supported by the company iText Software. Disclosure: I work there as QA Engineer, so I have argument from authority.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse Thanks I will do as you suggested. I didint know much about itext either. Thanks a lot for educating.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse I tried as you suggested. I added itextpdf 5.5.11 and removed itext 2.1.7 but it is generating `org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lowagie/text/DocumentException` please help

Comment: @AlexK Have added screenshot as you suggested

Comment: Apparently Jasper Reports expects the older version of iText, not the newer version.

Comment: This is the maven repository of [jasper-reports 6.2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/6.2.0), try to clean up your libraries (yes jasper-reports uses a specially version of itext 2.1.7.js4)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to all who helped.

The problem was not related to itext and was related to element styling.

The updated code is as follows.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="StockReport" pageWidth="1200" pageHeight="600" columnWidth="50" leftMargin="35" rightMargin="35" topMargin="50" bottomMargin="40">

<parameter name="Title" class="java.lang.String"/>


<field name="id" class="java.lang.Long"/>
<field name="dateTime" class="java.util.Date"/>


--------------------

<title>
<band height="50" splitType="Stretch">
<textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
    <reportElement x="0" y="5" width="960" height="30"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="Center">
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{Title}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
 </band>
 </title>
 <pageHeader>
 <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
<textField>
    <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="55" y="5" width="1000" height="15" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#8c8c8c"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="Center">
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Daily Reports"]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
 </band>
 </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
  <band height = "23">

     <staticText>
        <reportElement mode = "Opaque" x = "55" y = "3" 
           width = "1000" height = "15" backcolor = "#70A9A9" />

        <box>
           <bottomPen lineWidth = "1.0" lineColor = "#CCCCCC" />
        </box>

        <textElement />
        <text><![CDATA[]]> </text>
     </staticText>

-------------------------------------


     <staticText>
        <reportElement x = "85" y = "3" width = "100" height = "15" />

        <textElement textAlignment = "Center" verticalAlignment = "Middle">
           <font isBold = "true" />
        </textElement>

        <text><![CDATA[Date/Time]]></text>
     </staticText>

     <staticText>
        <reportElement x = "55" y = "3" width = "30" height = "15" />

        <textElement textAlignment = "Center" verticalAlignment = "Middle">
           <font isBold = "true" />
        </textElement>

        <text><![CDATA[#Id]]></text>
     </staticText>

  </band>
```

What i did is that I simply added a   element, with no text content to be used as column header banner and added the header text on top of it by specifying the position.

I am not sure of the logic behind this. As for the warning, the `Unpatched iText found, cannot use glyph rendering` still persits. I am not sure of how to resolve that, but the above cited helped me resolve the initial problem. I hope this would help if anyone come across a similar issue.

Once again thanks to all those who helped and as suggested in above comments I will try to do the same with updated libraries and will definitely edit my post with updated results if it help solve the issue.